# How can I develop the intuition of a team member?

Tags: training

I work in IT security profession as an IT auditor working in a lead / mentor role for my team.

Sometimes, **one may not have sufficient concrete evidence to come to a conclusion such as regarding whether fraud is present or not**. However, with intuition derived from a combination of experience and training, one can often tell more likely than not whether an event is legitimate or suspicious / fraudulent.

For example, in a batch of similar items, one might have a significantly different date much earlier or later than peers in the same batch, or transaction amounts just might be too "round"

**How can I develop the intuition of team members to pursue deeper investigations in these types of cases?**

Comment: The answer is in your question - with "a combination of experience and training". It worked for you, right?

Comment: Oh! I know this one! The specific training technique you're looking for is called perceptual learning (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perceptual_learning) I heard about it in this talk, conveniently titled "Cultivating Instinct", by Katrina Owen (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SKlIQLb7U00).

Answer (score 4):

I don't know whether this is applicable to your workflow or not, but you could get team members to pair up in some way.

**Player 1** - Has a first crack at a case and documents findings
**Player 2** - Has an independent view on the same case and also documents findings.

**Players 1 & 2** - compare notes and learn from each other.

The added benefit is that the findings from both players are combined into a greater total.  Case accuracy increases, employee ability increases.

Swap the teamings around so that sometimes experiences people effectively mentor less experienced team members, and equally skilled teamsters compete with each other.

You could explore gamification as well.